# Set log level to a JSP page - LOG4J

Tags: jsp, debugging, log4j

I have a log4j.properties file. I know how to set the log level to a particular class in the property file.

For example:

```
log4j.logger.com.mypackage.myclass=DEBUG
```

However, How do I set the log level to a particular JSP page, let's say myJSP.jsp, in the log4j.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept trying and eventually found out a solution. Hope it can help out someone who had the similar request.

```
log4j.logger.myJSP.jsp=DEBUG
```

Comment: i did something like this 
```
log4j.category.jsp_foobar=INFO, A1
log4j.additivity.jsp_foobar=false
``` where jsp_foobar is the logger name in the jsp file